# Why public IP receive from volley different from browser?

Tags: android, android-volley

i managed to create an android apps which able to get the device public ip via volley.Im using this website, http://v4.ipv6-test.com/api/myip.php.

When i browse the website using the browser, i get this ip 64.233.173.15 but when i request it using volley, it return this ip 123.136.111.227.

I already tried the following but failed:

- Use different website for volley
- Host own script to get public ip

What happen? What can i do to return the same ip as the browser?

## EDITED 1

**IpResolver Class**

```
public class PublicIPResolver {

    public static void getIPV4(Context context, Response.Listener<String> ip, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
    {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url ="http://beta.oligococo.tk/api/ipv4.php";
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, ip,errorListener);
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
PublicIPResolver.getIPV4(GooglePlayService.this, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String ipv4) {
                Toast.makeText(GooglePlayService.this, "IP Resolved! n my ip is : " +ipv4, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                myPref.saveToPref("Got_Internet","true");
                myPref.saveToPref("MyIP",ipv4);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(GooglePlayService.this,volleyError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myPref.saveToPref("Got_Internet","false");
                myPref.saveToPref("MyIP","");
            }
        });
```

## Edit 2

I tried to track the source of ip via google and its turn out to be my ISP.  Am i inside their LAN or what? But why browser able to show this ip 64.233.173.15 but when i request it using volley, it return this ip 123.136.111.227.

https://ipinfo.io/123.136.107.48

Comment: test it on real device if you are testing on emulator

Comment: I do tried it on real device. Its weird as on browser appear 64.*.*.* while using volley it return 123.19*.**

Comment: show the code how you doing it?

Comment: Hi, i just updated my question with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the answer. The IP is diffrent from result shown by Volley because my chrome browser is Data Saver enabled. It seem like the traffic has been reroute to their server or some kind of proxy. When i disabled the Data Save, i able to gain the same IP as provided by Volley